# How does media playback work in JavaFX2 and which codecs are supported by default?

Tags: java, standards, javafx, gstreamer

JavaFX 2 seems to ship with a completely new media playback API not related to any existing JavaSE API.

Some sources claim that the underlying functionality is provided by GStreamer. But I wonder if this only applies to Linux or to all supported platforms (Windows/Mac).

Can JavaFX use any codec supported by the platform's GStreamer library?
Or does JavaFX ship with its own internal version with limited codec support (and can additional codecs be added by the developer)?

How would a typical code example playing some audio or video look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing the [JavaFX FAQ](http://javafx.com/faq/#7):

> **7. Does JavaFX provide support for audio and video codecs?**
>
> JavaFX provides a common set of APIs that make it easy to include
>   media playback across all JavaFX enabled applications. The media
>   formats currently supported in the JavaFX 2.0 Beta release are the
>   following:
>
> - Audio: MP3; AIFF containing uncompressed PCM; WAV containing uncompressed PCM
> - Video: FLV containing VP6 video and MP3 audio

A comprehensive list of supported media formats for Java 8 is provided in the [Java 8 media Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

It can support more, but it's not straightforward :)

http://berry120.blogspot.com/2014/03/expanding-javafxs-media-support.html